# Absolute Position - Center - Max-width

Tags: html, css

I have som problems, regarding Max-width and Absolute Positioning.

In the top of my site, I have a '100%-width section' with a background-image.

I want a small image partly covering the bottom of the top image. To do so, I use Position:relative on the section (top image) and position:absolute on the small image. So far so good..

My problem is, that i want the small image to be centered and have a max-width, so it aligns to the content on the site. (Which have a max-width of 500px..)

I really can't figure out, how to do it...

So, is there a way to only affect vertically, when using position:absolute, or maybe something else i can do?

I hope it makes sense.. :)

screens:
http://cvdmark.com/images_help/screens.jpg

```
<body>

<section id="img_heading">
 <img src="#">
</section>

<section id="content">
 <ul>
  <li>
  </li>
 </ul>
</section>

</body>


body {
width:100%;
min-width:100%;
background-color:#000;
float:left;
}

#img_heading{
width:100%;
min-width:100%;
height:150px;
margin-bottom:6em;
background:url(../img/heading_img_test.jpg);
background-position: center center;
float:left;
position:relative;
}

#img_heading > img{
width:90%;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
bottom:-75px;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
max-width:500px;
/*left:5%;*/
background-color:#F69;  
}


#content{
width:90%;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
max-width:500px;
}   

#content ul{
width:100%;
list-style-type: none;
}

#content ul li{
width:100%;
float:left;
margin-bottom:30px;
}
```

JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rpatil/ukKgx/

Comment: It really make a lot of sense but can you add any image from paint-brush to explain your target.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you'd want is to align an absolute position div to the bottom of the section and center it.. (this following assumes you have your content in the section centered too..) replace div with img if you want to and give it your required id.. I ve given "foo-id"

```
div#foo-id
{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px; /*since you want it at the bottom of section*/
  z-index: 2;
  width:90%; /*since your asked for 90%*/
  max-width: 500px;
  /*the following to center your image*/
  margin-left:-45%;
  left:50%;
}
```

Believe that helps!

And here is an updated jsfiddle.. thanks @rubyist..
http://jsfiddle.net/ukKgx/2/

Comment: Thank You so much for your time!.. It works as long as it has a 500px width, but when i change the width to 90% as the rest of the content, it goes all crazy.. Any Thoughts? :)

Comment: @user3136720 guess I have changed a few things for your 90% issue.. let me know if it works.. and I edited the 30% to margin-left: 45%

Comment: @user3136720 : the general rule to center an absolute positioned element is to give a fixed width, margin-left: -(minus)half-of-width, left:50%. Guess this will help you in future.

Comment: Thank you for your heads up, Mohammed!.. I have updated the first post with some pictures, of what i want to achieve.. But i guess it won't be possible, due to the "fixed width rule" you referring to?.. :)

Comment: @user3136720 : fixed width means you specify the width be it a % value or a pixel value, the rule works.. check the fiddle..

Comment: Aaahh okay... Well, the "small image" isn't centered when scaling up the browser? :) By the way, I did not have enough power, to post pictures, so the original post is updated with a link.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an other solution to make it centred --> [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cha9chi/nhrmh/)

```
<section style="position: absolute; left: 50%;width:50%">
        <div style="position: relative; left: -50%;background-color:#ccc; border: dotted red 1px;width: 90%;max-width:500px;height:150px">
        </div>
    </section>
```

If you want to make it more custom, you have to use Javascript onLoad page to calculate screen width % picture width